# Hover on divs changes background smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a quick hub for two websites I created and I wanted to have two divs centered side by side, so that when you put your mouse over each div, it changes the body background image. I have made it so that when you hover over it, it changes the background but, its not smooth.

I really want to learn java script and I feel like this a good experience for me, thanks for any help

I'm using jQuery and Bootstrap.

Is there a way to just use css? if there isn't a way then its fine.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fre">
          <h3>Howdy</h3>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <div class="fre-moveleft smooth" id="fre">
              <img src="http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Image_03.png" class="scale">
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              <br> consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="med">
          <h3>Partner</h3>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <div class="med-moveright smooth" id="med">
              <img src="http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Image_03.png" class="scale">
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              <br> consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.scale {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

.smooth {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.med {
  float: left;
}

.med-moveright:hover {
  transform: translate(50px);
}

.fre {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.fre-moveleft:hover {
  transform: translate(-50px);
}


/*
body {
    background-image: url(../images/kabobi.jpg);

}
*/


/*
body .fre-moveleft:hover {
    background-image: url(http://img.mynet.com/ha2/tayyip.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
*/
```

**JS:**

```
$("#med").hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
});

$("#fre").hover(function() {
  $('body').css("background", "url(https://www.purinamills.com/2.purinamills.com/media/Images/MasterBrand/Lifestages/horse_lifestage_any-life-stage.png?ext=.png");
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/woqm9m9o/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you can fade between the two by toggling a class and setting a data attribute in jQuery, the rest controlled in CSS.

```js
var $body = $('body');

function setBg(str) {
  var bg = $body.attr('data-bg');
    $body.addClass('out');
    var t = setTimeout(function() {
      $body.attr('data-bg', str).removeClass('out');
    },250);
}

function hideBg() {
  $body.addClass('out');
}

$("#med img").hover(function() {
  setBg('med');
},function() {
  hideBg();
});

$("#fre img").hover(function() {
  setBg('fre');
},function() {
  hideBg();
});
```

```css
.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* These two lines are counted as one :-)       */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.scale {
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
}

.smooth {
  transition: 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.med {
  float: left;
}

.med-moveright:hover {
  transform: translate(50px);
}

.fre {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.fre-moveleft:hover {
  transform: translate(-50px);
}

/* new stuff */


body::before,
body::after {
  transition: opacity .25s;
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.out::after,
.out::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

[data-bg="med"]::before {
  background-image: url("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
}

[data-bg="fre"]::after {
  background-image: url("https://www.purinamills.com/2.purinamills.com/media/Images/MasterBrand/Lifestages/horse_lifestage_any-life-stage.png?ext=.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-center">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fre">
          <h3>Howdy</h3>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <div class="fre-moveleft smooth" id="fre">
              <img src="http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Image_03.png" class="scale">
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              <br> consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="med">
          <h3>Partner</h3>
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <div class="med-moveright smooth" id="med">
              <img src="http://www.logospike.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Logo_Image_03.png" class="scale">
            </div>
          </a>
          <div class="caption">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit
              <br> consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you also make it so that when take the cursor off the photo it goes back to the original background?

Comment: @Zoned yeah but I would probably re-approach the whole thing to do that, could be done a lot cleaner than how I have it. Updated my answer though, how's that?

Comment: @Zoned sweet, np :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add a transition to the body like this:

```
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zdwksre7/

This css will transition between the background in the body

Also, you can start experimenting adding classes with javascript with timeouts, so you can add more custom effects. Like fade, opacity, animate, etc. (Like, on hover, add the class 'fade' to the body (this class can have opacity: 0, and add to the body instead of a background-image, a opacity transition, wait 250ms, and then remove the class fade and change the background. This will make a smooth opacity transition between backgrounds)

You can see an example here
https://jsfiddle.net/866wwr0f/

Comment: can you also make it so that when take the cursor off the photo it goes back to the original background?